# sql prepared statement not showing output

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am new to prepared statements. This function is not showing any output.   What could the be problem?

```
function  selectFwhere($id) {
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','car_rental');
    $sql = mysqli_prepare($con,'SELECT * FROM `car_admin` WHERE admin_id = ?') or die("Unable to prepare statement: " . $con->error);
    $sql->bind_param('i',$id);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ echo " ".$row['admin_username']; }
    $sql->close();
    $con->close();

    selectFwhere(1);

}
```

Comment: at ``car_admin`` remove the quotes

Comment: @dean Those are backticks, and perfectly OK to have around a table name in mysql SQL.

Comment: AFAIK you need to do `$sql->bind_param($sql, 'i', $id);` Also, shouldn't you use `print_r();` instead of echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the line `selectFwhere(1);` outside the function body, after the closing `}`